# Backup Exec 9.1 for netware (Hang with scanning for network agent)

Tags: novell, backupexec

When I rebooted the netware 6.5 server with BackupExec v9.1, it keeps scanning for network agent and it keeps hang for scanning one of agent.

I'm trying to restart the backupexec but failed. How can I avoid scanning?

BTW, i tried to restart the remote agent but the scanning still hang on that point.

Kindly seed for any expert who can help on this problem....

Answer (score 0):

There is a bestart.nlm that starts the various processes.  There are a ton of command line switches which I forget that control what is started and not.

Look in the sys:\system\autoexec.ncf to find the start command you are executing to launch bestart.nlm on a restart.